# C# How to set non-user-inputted variable values/instances for an object (multiple classes)

Tags: c#, class, variables, object, instance

I'm working on a simple practice program and it works as it's supposed to.  However, it led me to realize that I'm fuzzy on an important area which I want to understand more thoroughly.  I created an object (or instance?) aPay.  The program asks the user to enter values for three variables (in the Main(Program) class).  Those values/instances are assigned to aPay.  aPay.WorkerName, aPay.HoursWorked, and aPay.RateOfPay.  I have a number of constants and variables with calculated values which are instantiated/calculated in the Pay class.  These are non-user-inputted values.  I want to send the values of each of those to the object aPay, similar to what was done with the user-inputted values.  I know it's not neccessary in this program, however it's useful in more complex programs and I'd like to understand how to achieve this.  I do not want to output anything more or alter the functioning of the program, I simply want to assign the values of the variables (GrossPay, NetPay, FicaTax, FedTax, StateTax, and HealthIns) to the aPay object. (I'm not sure if I'd use the variables (grossPay, netPay, fedTax, ficaTax, etc instead of the properties I just listed).

I know I could do this by doing Pay aPay = new Pay(workerName, hoursWorked, rateOfPay, grossPay, netPay, fedTax, ficaTax, stateTax, healthIns)

or something similar to this?

aPay = { workerName, hoursWorked, rateOfPay, grossPay, etc } ????

Can someone please explain how I could go about achieving this and provide example code using my code specifically?  I will list the code below:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Header();
        Directions();

        Pay aPay = new Pay();
        Write("**********************************\n");
        Write("Enter name:  ");
        aPay.WorkerName = ReadLine();

        Write("Enter hours: ");
        aPay.HoursWorked = double.Parse(ReadLine());

        Write("Enter rate:  ");
        aPay.RateOfPay = double.Parse(ReadLine());
        Write("**********************************\n");

        //
        //
        //
        //
        //

        WriteLine(aPay.ToString());

        ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Header()
    {
        WriteLine("*************************************************************");
        WriteLine("\t Pay");
        WriteLine("\t Calculate Net Pay");
        WriteLine("\t Matt Craig");
        WriteLine("\t " + DateTime.Today);
        WriteLine("*************************************************************");
    }

    private static void Directions()
    {
        WriteLine("This program will determine pay.");
        WriteLine(" ");
        WriteLine("You will be asked to enter hours worked" 
                  + "\n and rate of pay.");
        WriteLine(" ");
        WriteLine("*************************************************************");
    }
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Pay Class Below~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
public class Pay
{
    private string workerName;
    private double hoursWorked;
    private double rateOfPay;
    private double grossPay;
    private double netPay;
    private double FICA_TAX = 0.0765;
    private double FED_TAX = 0.20;
    private double STATE_TAX = 0.10;
    private double HEALTH_INS = 0.07;
    private double ficaTax;
    private double fedTax;
    private double stateTax;
    private double healthIns;

    public Pay()
    {

    }

    public string WorkerName
    {
        set
        {
            workerName = value;
        }
    }

    public double HoursWorked
    {
        set
        {
            hoursWorked = value;
        }
    }

    public double RateOfPay
    {
        set
        {
            rateOfPay = value;
        }
    }

    private double GrossPay
    {
        get
        {
            grossPay = Math.Round((hoursWorked * rateOfPay), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            return grossPay;
        }
    }

    private double NetPay
    {
        get
        {
            netPay = Math.Round((grossPay - ficaTax - fedTax - stateTax - healthIns), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            return netPay;
        }
    }

    private double FicaTax
    {
        get
        {
            ficaTax = Math.Round((FICA_TAX * grossPay), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            return ficaTax;
        }
    }

    private double FedTax
    {
        get
        {
            fedTax = Math.Round((FED_TAX * grossPay), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            return fedTax;
        }
    }

    private double StateTax
    {
        get
        {
            stateTax = Math.Round((STATE_TAX * grossPay), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            return stateTax;
        }
    }

    private double HealthIns
    {
        get
        {
            healthIns = Math.Round((HEALTH_INS * grossPay), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            return healthIns;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string stats;
        stats = string.Format("Name\t\t  {0} \n", workerName);
        stats += string.Format("Gross Pay\t  {0:c} \n", GrossPay);
        stats += string.Format("FICA tax\t  {0:c} \n", FicaTax);
        stats += string.Format("Federal tax\t  {0:c} \n", FedTax);
        stats += string.Format("State tax\t  {0:c} \n", StateTax);
        stats += string.Format("Health Insurance  {0:c} \n", HealthIns);
        stats += string.Format("Net pay\t\t  {0:c} \n", NetPay);
        return stats;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't constructor of class meant for this very purpose?

Comment: Create an instance and set its properties: `aPay.WorkerName = this.workerName;` etc. Your second code snippet with all the question marks should look like this: `var aPay = new Pay { WorkerName = this.workerName, HoursWorked = this.hoursWorked /* etc. */ };`. Your version looks like you might've done some JavaScript; the C# syntax differs in a few ways.

Comment: @Pankaj Kapare the assignment was to specifically use property procedures, and to not use constructors. But what I'm attempting isn't necessary for, or the point of the assignment I don't believe. Constructor is probly a good way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to describe is implemented using [constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx). Let's look at the code you have. You have a class `Pay` with a set of properties. For simplification I'm going to assume there are just three of them: `WorkerName`, `HoursWorked`, `RateOfPay` to start with.

Let's start with a class that describes these properties:

```
public class Pay
{
    public string WorkerName { get; set; }
    public double HoursWorked { get; set; }
    public double RateOfPay { get; set; }
}
```

There is a number of things I'd deem as "*wrong*" with the class definition above, but let's tackle one problem at a time.

First, we need to calculate health insurance cost. It depends on health insurance multiplier (0.7), which in our case is a static value. Let's add it to a class:

```
public class Pay
{
    private static double HEALTH_INS = 0.07;

    public string WorkerName { get; set; }
    public double HoursWorked { get; set; }
    public double RateOfPay { get; set; }

    private double HealthIns
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Round((HEALTH_INS * HoursWorked * RateOfPay), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        }
    }

    // With latest versions of C# you could actually do this:
    private double HealthInsAlt =>  Math.Round((HEALTH_INS * grossPay), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

Now, let's talk about your scenario: you'd like to assign these values. First of all, if the value is relevant and is used just within the class (`Pay` in this case) - doing what I've described above is totally fine and I personally prefer it this way - it's easy to read the code and understand where the value is coming from.

But sometimes (more complicated scenarios) it just does not work. Let's introduce a business case like this: the Health Insurance multiplier is now dynamic, depends on the rate of pay and is coming from a database. For simplification purposes, I'm going to assume that we can get it by using some kind of repository: `InsuranceMultipliersRepository.GetHealthMultiplier(RateOfPay)`.

We can retrieve the value in the constructor which is called when a new instance of an object with the specified class is created. Let's implement it:

```
public class Pay
{
    private static double HEALTH_INS { get; }

    public string WorkerName { get; set; }
    public double HoursWorked { get; set; }
    public double RateOfPay { get; set; }

    private double HealthIns
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Round((HEALTH_INS * HoursWorked * RateOfPay), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        }
    }

    public Pay() {
    // This is a parameterless constructor. C# compiler actually generates this for you behind the scenes and sets every value to the default for its type. We're basically saying "use this instead of default one when creating an object" and providing additional instructions. In our case, the instruction would be retrieving the multiplier from the repository and storing it within the Pay class property.

        var insuranceRepo = new InsuranceMultipliersRepository();

        this.HEALTH_INS = insuranceRepo.GetHealthMultiplier(RateOfPay);
    }
}
```

Now, there's a serious flaw there: we do not have the `RateOfPay` set yet! Which means that we need to modify the constructor to ensure that the `RateOfPay` value is known when we're creating a new instance of the `Pay` object. Let's do it:

```
public class Pay
{
    private static double HEALTH_INS { get; }

    public string WorkerName { get; set; }
    public double HoursWorked { get; set; }
    public double RateOfPay { get; set; }

    private double HealthIns
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Round((HEALTH_INS * HoursWorked * RateOfPay), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        }
    }

    public Pay(double rateOfPay) {
        var insuranceRepo = new InsuranceMultipliersRepository();
        this.RateOfPay = rateOfPay;
        this.HEALTH_INS = insuranceRepo.GetHealthMultiplier(rateOfPay);
    }
}
```

Ok, looks better now. But by changing the constructor to be *parameterized*, we've effectively made the following code invalid: `var somePay = new Pay();`. C# compiler will not generate default parameterless constructors for class implementations (it will still do so in some scenarios, for abstract classes for example).

Couple of things worth mentioning: you can see that there is no `set` method for `HEALTH_INS` but we are still setting the value. How? The reality is that we are allowed to set `readonly` properties or properties without a setter in a constructor (with C#6+). If you are using C#5 or earlier versions you will have to create a backing property (*for public properties, if you have a private one it's safe to simply leave the setter there, noone can see it anyway*), something like this if we need to make our insurance multiplier public and readable:

```
public class Pay
{
    private static double _HEALTH_INS { get; set; }

    public double HEALTH_INS { get { return _HEALTH_INS; } }
    public string WorkerName { get; set; }
    public double HoursWorked { get; set; }
    public double RateOfPay { get; set; }

    private double HealthIns
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Round((HEALTH_INS * HoursWorked * RateOfPay), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        }
    }

    public Pay(double rateOfPay) {
        var insuranceRepo = new InsuranceMultipliersRepository();
        this.RateOfPay = rateOfPay;
        this._HEALTH_INS = insuranceRepo.GetHealthMultiplier(rateOfPay);
    }
}
```

Another thing I've noticed about your code: your public properties have setters. This effectively makes your class *mutable*. It means that you can never be sure that the value of the property has not been changed/is correct. Imagine a scenario: you create an instance of `Pay` object and set the `RateOfPay`. You pass this object to methods, use it in different places. Then, by mistake, you or other developer write kind of code:

```
public void AdjustPayForHours (Pay payToAdjust)
{
    // If someone worked for less than half an hour their rate of pay should be reduced in half
    if (payToAdjust.HoursWorked < 0.5) {
        payToAdjust.RateOfPay = payToAdjust.RateOfPay * 5.0
    }
}
```

Now, you see what's going on. It should be `payToAdjust.RateOfPay * 0.5` but there is a typo which can significantly affect other pieces of the application/business. It is possible because your class is mutable. My ***personal*** opinion ***regarding the types, interfaces and other objects defining the domain model***: no class ***property*** (*update 03/20/2017 added the missed word*) should have public setters<sup>**1**</sup>. All properties should be set in a constructor. If mutability is required properties should be changed via methods. If mutability is not required - properties should be readonly and setters should either not exist or be private<sup>**2**</sup>. Preferably, all properties should be private and values should be retrieved using methods as well. Again, this is my personal opinion, it may be wrong, sub-optimal, but that's what I believe in. It's, for sure, the safest way. Here's an example (*C#7 based, for C#5 and earlier you will need a separate backing property for each public property*):

```
public class Worker
{
    // Here the property is public, so you'd be able to do the following:
    // var contractor = new Worker("John");
    // string contractorName = contractor.WorkerName;
    public string WorkerName { get; }

    public Worker(string workerName)
    {
         this.WorkerName = workerName;
    }
}

public class Pay
{
    private static double HEALTH_INS { get; }

    // Three properties below are private and are set in the constructor.
    // The "HoursWorked" has a setter because sometimes we need to add hours.
    // Others don't because we set them once when we create an object
    // You're NOT able to do:
    // var someWorkersPay = new Worker();
    // var someWorkersRate = someWorkersPay.RateOfPay;
    private string WorkerName { get; }
    private double HoursWorked { get; set; }
    private double RateOfPay { get; }

    public double GrossPay { get { return HoursWorked * RateOfPay; } }
    private double HealthIns
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Round((HEALTH_INS * HoursWorked * RateOfPay), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        }
    }

    public Pay(Worker workerWithPay, double hoursSpent, double payRate) {
        var insuranceRepo = new InsuranceMultipliersRepository();
        this.WorkerName = workerWithPay.WorkerName;
        this.HoursWorked = hoursSpent;
        this.RateOfPay = payRate;
        this._HEALTH_INS = insuranceRepo.GetHealthMultiplier(rateOfPay);
    }

    public void AddHoursWorked(double hoursToAdd) {
        this.HoursWorked += hoursToAdd;
    }

    public double GetRateOfPay() {
        return this.RateOfPay;
    }

    // Now you can do someWorkersPay.GetRateOfPay();
}
```

*Update 03/20/17: Implementation above does not make the object deeply immutable, but can be classified as shallow immutability.*

Finally, you've asked about larger applications. In a larger codebase, developers use different patterns. For my scenario (insurance multiplier in the database) two would be most useful: Inversion of control and Dependency Injection.

There are a lot of articles and docs online on these two patterns, so I won't go into the details. Just a simple explanation: using these allows developers to avoid thinking about the location of the health insurance rates, how the should get it (inversion of control) and also allows to avoid creating new instances of repositories (or other dependencies) when we need to instantiate a new object. In my example `InsuranceMultipliersRepository` is a dependency of `Pay` - we need it to create a new `Pay`. Dependency injection allows us to do something like this:

```
public class Pay
{
    private static readonly IHealthInsuranceRepository _insuranceRepo { get; }        

    public string WorkerName { get; set; }
    public double HoursWorked { get; set; }
    public double RateOfPay { get; set; }

    private double HealthMultiplier { get { return _insuranceRepo.GetHealthMultiplier(RateOfPay); } }

    private double HealthIns
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Round((HealthMultiplier * HoursWorked * RateOfPay), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        }
    }

    public Pay(double rateOfPay, IHealthInsuranceRepository healthInsuranceRepository) {
        _insuranceRepo = healthInsuranceRepository;
        this.RateOfPay = rateOfPay;
    }
}
```

Note: my code is just an example, it's recommended to separate concerns further with different layers (repository, service, application logic, domain, etc.).

---

1: [Property Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006(v=vs.110).aspx)

2: [Field Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229057(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: "Immutable data structures are the future" does not mean "every class should be immutable right now". Not even close. Link me these "best practices". More of your imaginative reinterpretation, I suppose.

Comment: @EdPlunkett No problem: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006(v=vs.110).aspx Now, I believe your next answer can be: these are guidelines, the are not that specific, this is my reinterpretation... Well, the thing is, I don't BS people. When I say something that is not a fact, a make sure to say that it's my opinion. Based on my understanding of the guidelines and experience. Now, anyone can have a different understanding of the guidelines and different experience. Neither the outlook nor the experience gives one a permission to offend instead of presenting a case.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Oh, and another one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229057(v=vs.110).aspx . Quote: "The principle of encapsulation is one of the most important notions in object-oriented design. This principle states that data stored inside an object should be accessible only to that object."

Comment: I was referring to this bizarre claim: **"all objects in C# should be immutable .... I can also point to .NET best practices, which state the same"** Show me the MS best practices page that says, implies, or suggests that "all objects in C# should be immutable". That one. You used the term "immutable" and linked to something about immutable collections that you either hopelessly misunderstood, or didn't even read.

Comment: @EdPlunkett All objects in the **domain model**. I already gave the link. "A useful way to interpret the principle is to say that a type should be designed so that changes to fields of that type (name or type changes) can be made without breaking code other than for members of the type. This interpretation immediately implies that all fields must be private." It's the second one.

Comment: Again, you've sent me a link to another page which assumes everywhere that all classes are mutable. You understand very little of what you are sending me. You have no business pretending to understand this subject. I see you're a manager of some kind with some SQL. Did you take a C# class or something?

Comment: Yes, all fields should be private, unless they're readonly. Tea in China is a bit high this week. That's fascinating. Now let's get back to your bizarre belief that all objects must be immutable.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I believe it would be benefitial for you to learn the difference between observational, shallow, deep, popsicle and realio-trulio immutability

Comment: @EdPlunkett And, especially if you examine the code examples I've provided, I implied (my bad, sorry) shallow immutability.

Comment: Quote: **"no class should have public setters"**. That was you, son. Nothing amazes me more than a BSer who gets repeatedly shown to be an utter clown, and still thinks he's getting away with it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah, keep looking at it. Missed a word, great. After it I say *All properties should be set in a constructor.*

Comment: @EdPlunkett If you have nothing else to do, keep trying to find inconsistencies in my answer, you will find more. If that is what you like - enjoy. If that is what gives you a feeling of supremacy - I'm glad you can have this kind of experience at my expense. I'm done feeding the troll here, have a good one.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out your response. The assignment asked for properties to be used in place of constructors. When I get to my desktop I'll take some time and try to understand your answer more deeply. @Phil P.

Comment: @Snags Take care, he's a very inexperienced amateur programmer largely just making stuff up. Before you try to follow one of his crazy "opinions", ask for advice about it on SO. You'll get answers. The following is 100% wrong **according to the sources he links**: *"If mutability is required properties should be changed via methods. ... Preferably, all properties should be private and values should be retrieved using methods as well."* Private readonly properties with public methods to call the property getters? He doesn't seem to know that property getters and setters ARE methods.

Comment: @Snags, I strongly recommend reading the stuff under the links I've referenced in the answer. They have more detail on best practices (which, as you might notice, can be interpreted differently).

Comment: @Snags, also, true, setters and getters are accessor methods. My recommendation is to use non-accessor methods is based on the following guideline recommendation, quote: "Property getters should be simple operations and should not have any preconditions. If a getter can throw an exception, it should probably be redesigned to be a method. Notice that this rule does not apply to indexers, where we do expect exceptions as a result of validating the arguments"

Comment: @EdPlunkett @ Phil P.   Thanks both of you.  I'll see what I come up with.